# Errors in sending sms through java

Tags: java, ozeki

I am trying to send sms through java to mobile phones using free sms sites like way2sms ,etc. 
I have searched the net for many external jar files but nothing is working. I have also an mtnl connection and i tried to connect to it using Ozeki but it is giving me an error  - 
Login could not be completed due to timeup.

Please reply someone  who has already send sms in java.

Comment: Show us your code and your exception. How should we help you if we do not know what you do?

Answer (score 1):

While your question specifically asks for "using sites like way2sms, etc", an alternative is to use the email to SMS feature that all carriers seem to provide. So you'd just use JavaMail and fill in the information accordingly. Downside is you have to have different information for each carrier. I've done this before and it works very well.

For example from AT&T:
http://www.att.com/esupport/article.jsp?sid=KB63037&cv=820#fbid=gFn39JcTTp6

> To send a text, picture, or video message to an AT&T wireless device from your email:

- Text message: Address your email to the recipient's 10-digit wireless
  phone number, followed by @txt.att.net, for example,
  5551234567@txt.att.net.
- Picture or video message: Address your email
  to the recipient's 10-digit wireless phone number, followed by
  @mms.att.net, for example, 5551234567@mms.att.net.
- Don't include dashes or spaces in between the numbers.

JavaMail API:
https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home